# MBP Retina 2015: Graphical glitches after update to 10.12.4

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spotify

my Macbook Pro has random graphical glitches. Most of the time they are present in Spotify, and less often in Chrome. An example of such glitches is on the photo attached.

[image: Spotify Glitches]

Is there a known solution to this problem?

Comment: Is that a screenshot or a picture? If that is a picture, see if the glitches appear in screenshots as well

Comment: It's a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone (see this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7908354?start=0&tstart=0). I had the same artifacts and reverting to 10.12.3 "solved" everything. Let's hope this bug will be fixed with the release of MacOS 10.12.5 (sadly, I doubt it).